# Error when chaining with chomp

Tags: ruby

I wrote a small program as the following

```
print "Your string = "
input = gets.chomp.downcase!

if input.include? "s"
   puts "Go yourself!"
end
```

But I got the error

> undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

if I delete the exclamation mark (!) after downcase, the program runs properly.

I don't understand the reason.

Comment: Vu, it's not just `downcase!` that behaves this way.  There are several `String` methods ending with `!` that return nil if no change is made (unlike their non-`!` counterparts), such as  `slice!`, `capitalize!`, `chop!` and `reverse!`. Examples from `Array` that have this behavior include `reverse!`, `sort!`, `flatten!`, `slice!`, `compact!` and `reject!`.  btw, you don't need `chomp` here, unless it's needed for code not shown.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't understand your last sentence "unless it's needed for code not shown". Can you say it more clearly?

Comment: By that I meant, "unless it's needed elsewhere in your program".  Suppose, for example, you removed `chomp` and your code were followed by `if input == 'cat' ...`.  Your code would run fine, but `input == 'cat'` would always evaluate `false`, because `'cat' != 'cat\n'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String#downcase!` will give you `nil`, if the string is already in down-cased. So use `String#downcase`, it is safe. I am sure, you passed from the command line to the method `gets`, a string which is already down-cased. Replace the line `input = gets.chomp.downcase!` with `input = gets.chomp.downcase`. Now you are safe.

[`String#downcase`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase)

> Returns a copy of str with all uppercase letters replaced with their lowercase counterparts. If the receiver string object is already, downcased, then the receiver will be returned.

[`String#downcase!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase-21)

> Downcases the contents of str, returning nil if no changes were made.

One example to demonstrate this -

```
>> s = "abc"
>> p s.downcase
"abc"
>> p s.downcase!
nil
```

Now `nil` is an instance of the class [`NilClass`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/NilClass.html), which has no instance method called `#include?`. So you got `no method error`. This is obvious.

```
>> nil.respond_to?(:downcase)
false
>> nil.respond_to?(:downcase!)
false
>> s.respond_to?(:downcase!)
true
>> s.respond_to?(:downcase)
true
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `downcase!` as it can return `nil` if no changes have been made to the string.

Therefore, the correct code will be:

```
print "Your string = "
input = gets.chomp.downcase

if input.include? "s"
   puts "Go yourself!"
end
```